# Handle Routed Events in WPF user control loaded from a dll at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have an WPF control library, I successfully load its assembly from main app and show the user control I want. The problem is that I want to handle keyboard routed event for usercontrol but it seems that the message never reach to it. Advice?:

My scenario
Main App Window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Apollo.Clock.UI.ClockWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>     
        <StackPanel x:Name="MainContainer"></StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Loading user control from main app windows:

```
UserControl myControl = null;
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("AppUI.WPF.dll");
Type[] tlist = asm.GetTypes();
foreach (Type t in tlist){
    if (t.FullName == "DefaultSkin"){
        myControl = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as UserControl;
        MainContainer.Children.Add(myControl);
        break;
    }
}
```

DefaultSkin xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DefaultSkin"
Keyboard.PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">
```

DefaultSkin.cs

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
            e.Handled = true;
            //more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will only handle the event in case you press a key inside the usercontrol.

To set the focus you can use the following:

after Activiting the user control handle the IsVisibleChanged:

```
myControl.IsVisibleChanged += SetKeyboardFocus;
```

and have SetKeyboardFocus method:

```
void SetKeyboardFocus(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  IInputElement inputElement = sender as IInputElement;
  inputElement.Focusable = true;
  Keyboard.Focus(inputElement);
}
```

Comment: The usercontrol occupy the hole window surface, there is no chance it lost focus.